# How should I store a 256 bit number in C# and perform math operations on it?

Tags: c#, arrays, bit-manipulation, largenumber, uint64

I need to store a 256bit number in memory and perform basic math operations on it.

How do I go about doing this in C#?  Is there a library I should be using?

Comment: [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would the [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) type suit your needs? It

> Represents an arbitrarily large signed integer.

And provides the expected arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 1):

[BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28VS.100%29.aspx) maybe an option.

If you need just 256 bits and do special hadling of over/underflows - you may have to do it yourself (or find some existing library that is not part of .Net Framework).